# Sql server staged operation in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table like this

```
id | userId | point | type
1     3        3       1
2     3        5       1 
3     3        6       1
4     3        2       2
5     4        5       1
```

What i want to get is

```
userId | totalPoint
  3         28
  4         5
```

The way i calculate is to sum all points where type is 1 and multiply total of this sum by point where type is 2

Example : (3+5+6)*2 = 28

I tried many queries but i couldnt get it

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Just study GROUP BY and the solution is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little trickier than it first seems.  You want conditional aggregation, and to be careful about missing "2" values:

```
select userid,
       (sum(case when type = 1 then point else 0 end) *
        coalesce(sum(case when type = 2 then point end), 1)
       )
from t
group by userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this math trick to create a product aggregate:

```
 SELECT
       userid, 
       exp(SUM(LOG(ABS(NULLIF(field, 0)))))  
    FROM
       (select distinct userid, type, sum(point) over(partition by userid, type order by userid)field  from #temp 
group by userid, type, point)a
    GROUP BY
       userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using only SELECT, subquery and group by here

```
SELECT USER_ID,
     (SELECT SUM(POINT) FROM THETABLE b 
        WHERE a.USER_ID = b.USER_ID AND TYPE = 1
        GROUP BY b.USER_ID, TYPE)
             *
     (SELECT SUM(POINT) FROM THETABLE c
        WHERE a.USER_ID = c.USER_ID AND TYPE = 2
        GROUP BY b.USER_ID, TYPE)
     AS TOTAL_POINT
 FROM THETABLE a
```